# how to run a menu item script across selected sheet tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to accomplish running this border script across only certain sheet tabs, and I have been unsuccessful at calling this across them. the sheet tabs are as follows. Current Sales, Pending Orders, Subcontract Orders, Partial Shipped, Quotes, Archived Sales.

```html
function setborders() {
 var menu = [{name: "Borders for nonempty cells", functionName: "borders"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Set Borders", menu);
}

function borders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var numsheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s]
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:V1000");
    var values = range.getValues();
    var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < allsheets.length; i++) 
   if(['Current Sales','Pending Orders','Subcontract Orders','Partial Shipped','Quotes','Archived Sales'].indexOf(allsheets[i].getName())){
  
  if(sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue()) {
    range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0]) { // Only for non-empty A column cells
        sheet.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      }
    }
       
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][14]) { 
        sheet.getRange("O" + (i + offsetRow) + ":O" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][18]) { 
        sheet.getRange("S" + (i + offsetRow) + ":S" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][19]) { 
        sheet.getRange("T" + (i + offsetRow) + ":T" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][20]) { 
        sheet.getRange("U" + (i + offsetRow) + ":U" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][21]) { 
        sheet.getRange("V" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: unless setborders() is called from onOpen(), you should probably rename it to onOpen(), so that the menu item is created when the spreadsheet is opened. Apart from that I don't see what the issue is. If I put data in A2 and T2, in multiple worksheets, then this row is given a border when running borders(), and T2 has a thick border. What is it that you think isn't working?

Comment: There is a trigger set up for setborders() being called from onOpen()

Comment: I must have had a outage, this script is working now. but how would I restrict this to just the specified sheets?

Comment: Stack Snippet should be used only for client side executable code (HTML/CSS/JavaScript)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? i inserted the code ran it and saved it.

Comment: The code in the question only could be executed on Google Apps Script not on this page. Stack Snippet is the feature that you used to post the code but it's purpose is to offer to readers a button to execute the code but your code can't be executed.

Comment: Regarding the last revision, I think that you should not edited the original code on this question, you could add it at the end as a way to share your continued efforts to find the solution to the problem by yourself but since you are applying a suggestion given in an answer that already has upvotes, I think that it really is a follow up question and in such case it should be posted as a new question. Anyway I edited my answer.

Comment: My apologies, still learning

Comment: Unrelated: Looks like you are getting closer to the 50 points required to make comments on other content ... that would be how you ask people questions then. One thought btw: the person you "answered" asked something ... he wasnt online for two years. Chances are that he wont come back ever. That is also something to check before dropping comments.

Answer (score 2):

## [Revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54331937/5)

The "fix" didn't work because the code has nested `for`s, both iterating through all sheets. The inner for has the suggested condition but the outer for not.

## [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54331937/1)

To limit the execution certain parts of the code to specific spreadsheet you could use the `getName()` method of Class Sheet and compare it with the list of the valid sheets. One way of doing this is creating an array of the valid sheet names an use `indexOf`.

Let say that the valid sheet names are Sheet1 and Sheet3, and that `sheets` is a collection of all the sheets resulting from something like `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();`), then the following code will iterate over all the sheets, but only execute one part of the code on the valid sheets:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) 
   if(['Sheet1','Sheet3'].indexOf(sheets[i].getName())){
     //Add here the code to be executed on the valid sheets
   }
}
```

Comment: Apologies again, I've been racking my brain on how to make this work. have tried many things without success. could I share my sheet with you?

Comment: @Shane Sure, but before doing that make a [mcve]. In other words, 1. Create a new spreadsheet, add to the minimum of sheets and values necessary to be able to do the task in focus and test a simplified version of your script. 2. Make a simplified version of your script. 3. Share the spreadsheet with anyone with the link, 4. Post a new question, 5. Add the link to the new question here.