# Running script across specific sheets within spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

> NOTE:This is a follow of of [how to run a menu item script across selected sheet tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54331937/1595451)

I am trying to run this script across only the specified sheets to draw borders as set up in the code. Can someone assist in correcting the code. I found great information on this post [Stack overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211504/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getrange-of-null-line-0)  I am now having issues with line 11 , TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. If I am able to consolidate the borders portion of the script I am unsure of how. [test sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JzihQG65gnhfbJji18HMByMUcZfilr9QiR2LSO_z5-k/edit?usp=sharing)

```html
function setborders() {
 var menu = [{name: "Apply Borders", functionName: "borders"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Set Borders", menu);
}

function borders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:V1000");
    var values = range.getValues();
    var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex();
    
              
    range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0]) { // Only for non-empty A column cells
        sheet.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      }
    }
       
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][14]) { 
        sheet.getRange("O" + (i + offsetRow) + ":O" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][18]) { 
        sheet.getRange("S" + (i + offsetRow) + ":S" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][19]) { 
        sheet.getRange("T" + (i + offsetRow) + ":T" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][20]) { 
        sheet.getRange("U" + (i + offsetRow) + ":U" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][21]) { 
        sheet.getRange("V" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
function setborders() {
 var menu = [{name: "Apply Borders", functionName: "borders"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Set Borders", menu);
}

function borders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_name = ['Current Sales','Pending Orders', 'Subcontract Orders', 'Partial Shipped', 'Quotes', 'Archived Sales']; 
  for (s=0; s<sheet_name.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name[s]);
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:V1000");
    var values = range.getValues();
    var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex();
    
              
    range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0]) { // Only for non-empty A column cells
        sheet.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      }
    }
       
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][14]) { 
        sheet.getRange("O" + (i + offsetRow) + ":O" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][18]) { 
        sheet.getRange("S" + (i + offsetRow) + ":S" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][19]) { 
        sheet.getRange("T" + (i + offsetRow) + ":T" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][20]) { 
        sheet.getRange("U" + (i + offsetRow) + ":U" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][21]) { 
        sheet.getRange("V" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a better way to do this, but here's one solution:

```
var menu = [{name: "Borders for nonempty cells", functionName: "borders"}];
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

if(sheetName === 'Name of sheet') {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Set Borders", menu);
}
else {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().removeMenu("Set Borders");
}
```

Comment: problem is the border script part is calling "sheet" which is including all the sheets and not the ones selected.

Comment: I'm sorry can you please clarify which part?

Comment: I"m not sure how to apply your edits to my script. I need the script to run on sheet tabs ('Current Sales','Pending Orders','Subcontract Orders','Partial Shipped','Quotes','Archived Sales')

Comment: Use if ([‘name1’, ‘name2’, etc].includes(sheetName()))

Answer (score 0):

The code has several flaws that are making you have difficulties to apply the answer to your previous question

1. Indentation is not applied properly
2. Multiple  `for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++)`
3. Having a for loop to iterate over all sheets inside another for loop that also iterate over all sheets.

Suggestions

1. Clean-up your code

   1. Apply indentation properly
   2. Move all the

      ```
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][/*a number */]) { 
        // Call to setBorder
      }
      ```

      into one

      ```
      for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {...}
      ```
2. Remove `for(var i = 0; i < allsheets.length; i++)`
3. Add `if(!['Current Sales','Pending Orders','Subcontract Orders','Partial Shipped','Quotes','Archived Sales'].indexOf(sheets.getName())) return;` just below of `var sheet=allsheets[s]`

Comment: I still cannot get this code to work, and i'm am unsure of how to combine all my if (values[i][0] && values[i][/*a number */]) into one.

Comment: I still am unable to get this code to run on the selected sheets, I have tried many changes, searching and using different methods with no success.

Comment: @Shane I suggest you to start from scratch. Start by doing something simple on all sheets, like adding a value to cell A1, then modified that script to add a value to A2 to some sheets, and so on.

Comment: I'm not starting from scratch, I re posted the question like you advised. I appreciate the help but its still not helping me correct this to run across the selected sheets, all of your answers did not work when applied to my code.